# Display NULL instead of zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get NULL values instead of zero in my query.I put a condition where the varchar '0.0000' is not supposed to display along with NULL value. When the outcome comes, NULL is not displayed but 0.0000 is still showing there. Is there anyway i can convert that varchar to NULL so that the value is not displayed?

Comment: Please show what query have you written

Comment: Is the column in your table nullable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select case when your_column = '0.0000' then null
            else your_column
       end as your_column
from your_table
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answer. For me, the one with Select CASE worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`NULLIF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx):

> Returns a null value if the two specified expressions are equal.

```
SELECT NULLIF(Column, '0.0000') As Column
FROM dbo.TableName
```

Comment: @Patrick: "Is there anyway i can convert that varchar to NULL?" So he wants to treat the varchar `'0.0000'` as `NULL`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: yes, exactly what `NULLIF` does.

Comment: what about IF()

`IF(Expressio_TRUE, VAL1, NULL)`

Comment: @PatrickHofman - are you perhaps thinking of `ISNULL`/`COALESCE`? That's not what Tim's recommending.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: You are right, my bad. Tim: my apologies.